# Where can I learn about the reflection/refraction of sound waves and acoustic impedance in a way similar to quantum tunnelling?

Tags: waves, acoustics, resource-recommendations, scattering

I have learnt about the reflection and transmission of a particle at a potential barrier in quantum mechanics. I vaguely remember there is something similar in acoustics - things such as acoustic impedance of sounds and the proportion transmitted (refracted) and reflected. Where can I learn about those concepts in acoustics? Any book recommendations? I am particularly interested to see how the classical wave theory is linked to quantum mechanics.

It appears that I should learn acoustics before QM? Am I doing it in the wrong order?

Comment: Any good book on Partial Differential Equations (PDEs), which cover the wave equation in detail should be what you’re looking for. Schrodinger’s equation (QM) is essentially a special form of the wave equation, so it would make sense to learn the wave equation before Schrodinger’s. Transmission vs reflection is a property of the wave equation, and applies to QM, acoustics, optics, or any other wave-like phenomena. Though I personally don’t know of a great book for this... just trying to narrow your search.